# Program crashes after loading image (GDIplus)

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

I wanted to write a program which loads an image given by command line and afterwards does something with it. My problem now is: Whenever I execute the program it prints me the palette size of the image (which gives me a wrong output (12) for every picture in jpg format I enter), and afterwards it crashes, but I can not figure out my mistake.
What am I doing wrong?

```
inline bool exists(const std::string& name) {
    if (FILE *file = fopen(name.c_str(), "r")) {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Too few/too much arguments. Usage: ShrinkImage <Input-File> <Number of target colours>\n";
        return 0;
    }
    int num_colors;
    char * filepath = argv[1];
    if (!exists(filepath))
    {
        std::cout << "File does not exist.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    num_colors = std::stoi(argv[2], nullptr);
    ULONG_PTR(m_gdiplusToken);
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusstartupinput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusstartupinput, NULL);
    const size_t cSize = strlen(filepath) + 1;
    size_t Size = cSize - 1;
    wchar_t *wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
    swprintf(wc, cSize, L"%hs", filepath);
    Gdiplus::Image image(wc);
    std::cout << image.GetPaletteSize() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Printed PaletteSize\n";

    delete wc;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);
    std::cout << "After Shutdown\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num_colors = (int)argv[2];` casts the pointer to integer, instead of parsing the string. use e.g. `std::stoi`.

Comment: I know, but I don't think that this is the reason for the crash.

Comment: what does the format string `L"%hs"` mean

Comment: I would expect that if you pass in a bad filename, getting palette size may not work...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: What do you mean with "a bad filename"? Even if I check if the file exists the problem continues...

Comment: How do you check that the filename exists? And yes, I meant a file that can't be opened.

Comment: See above for updated code.

Comment: I can reproduce the crash (*with* initialized startup info) and it disappears when the image object is allocated dynamically. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You mean `Gdiplus::Image *image = new Gdiplus::Image(wc)` ?

Comment: Thanks, see my answer, too (and someone already voted it down, I don't know why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:
Writing instead of

```
Gdiplus::Image image(wc);
```

this:

```
Gdiplus::Image * image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(wc);
delete image;
image = 0;
```

This solves my problem.